# Iphone contact photo

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I tried to search an answer for this but couldn't find one.

My iPhone application needs to access the Photo associated with the contact in the phonebook. However, it also needs to make sure that every time application is launched, it verifies that the photo is the same. 
So, in essence, I am trying to access the photo used by contacts database for a person's phone number or email address. 
- Is there a way for me to do this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to search harder

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABPersonCopyImageData